# Rendering an Array via Mustache

Tags: arrays, json, mustache

So I've got some data

```
{"facility":[{"ID":"A1A123","Name":" Anytown Health Centre PHCY","RegionID":1}]}
```

And I'd like to render it using a Mustache template that can be used to render either a single html table row, or multiple rows i.e. the object in the array can be 1 or greater.

The template looks like this

```
{{#facility}}
<form hx-put="/facility/{{ID}}">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{Name}}">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Region</label>
    <input type="text" name="RegionID" value="{{RegionID}}">
  </div>
</form>
{{/facility}}
```

So I can see the mismatch between my template looking for data in the form of facility.ID etc.

How do I structure the template to iterate over an array data tagged "facility" inside of an object ?

Comment: `{{#section}}{{/section}}` automatically iterates arrays, so this template should already give you a `<form>` for each element in the `facility` array. Is this not what you get? What do you get instead? What Mustache engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after 45 mins of google and some playing around I've got a working template which I'll share back here (in case I need to do this again in 3 years LOL) and for others to stumble across.

```
enter code here
{{#facility}}
{{#}}
<form hx-put="/facility/{{ID}}">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{Name}}">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Region</label>
    <input type="text" name="RegionID" value="{{RegionID}}">
  </div>
</form>
{{/}}
{{/facility}}
```

The key is to allow for the extra level of iteration. Mustache does not care if it is iterating over an object (by name) or an array (by ordinal)

Comment: Mustache DOES care whether `facility` is an object or an array; it does NOT iterate objects. My guess is that the `{{#}}{{/}}` pair in your template is a no-op and that it would also work without. Your Mustache engine likely searched for an empty string `''` property in the context, which it didn't find, then defaulted to `undefined` and then looked up the `Name` and `RegionID` in lower context frames, where it found the actual array element from `{{#facility}}{{/facility}}`. Try it with https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/playground.html.